# Multiply columns with rows by matching column name and row name in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame which looks like this

```
> data
  A B
1 1 2
2 2 1
```

I have a reference data frame which looks like this

```
> ref
  Names Values
1     A      5
2     B     10
```

I want to multiply each column by corresponding row in Ref having same Name

the result should be this

```
> result
   A  B
1  5 20
2 10 10
```

What is the fastest way to achieve this in R? Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can `match` the column names of 'data' with 'Names' column of 'ref', get the corresponding 'Values' based on the numeric index and then multiply by replicating the `ref$Values`

```
data*ref$Values[match(names(data), ref$Names)][col(data)]
#   A  B
#1  5 20
#2 10 10
```

Comment: What if I only want to multiply a subset of columns from data?

Comment: @TiberiusGracchus2020 THen you can change `data[yourcols]  <-data[yourcols] * ref$Values[match(yourcols, ref$Names)][col(data[yourcols)]`

Answer (score 1):

If you use `Names` for `rownames` instead in `ref`, you could do something like this as well

```
rownames(ref) <- ref$Names #assign rownames
ref$Names <- NULL #drop col

i <- intersect(rownames(ref), colnames(data)) #find intersect
mapply(`*`, ref[i, ], data[, i]) #perform multiplication
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    5   20
#[2,]   10   10
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
for (n in seq(along = names(data))) {
    data[,n] <- data[,n] * ref$Values[which(ref$Names == names(data)[n])]
}
```